# Which one is quicker/optimized - Inner Join or Partition By - to obtain Aggregated data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, window-functions

In my data 'table1', there are multiple records for each app_id. I'm trying to get a latest app_id entry. Which one of the below queries would be quick or better to consider in terms of performance and memory usage? Currently, I work on AWS server and use PostgreSQL.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM 
    (SELECT app_id, max(datetime) as datetime
    from table1
    group by 1) a
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
    from table1) b
ON a.app_id = b.app_id AND a.datetime = b.datetime
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by app_id order by datetime DESC 
    NULLS LAST) as num FROM table1) sub
WHERE sub.num=1
```

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) using `explain (analyze, buffers)  ....`

Comment: Please read Eric Lippert's [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Hi. Read about relational query optimization/implementation. Eg in Wikipedia or any of dozens of database textbooks free online in pdf. Then read some books about SQL optimization.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right answer to "which is faster" is to try the queries on your data and your systems.

That said, there are some considerations in favor of `row_number()`.  In particular, window functions are not an "accidental" feature in databases.  Adding a new string function is just a function and the function may or may not be optimized.

On the other hand, window functions required rewriting/redesigning some fundamental components of the database engine.  In general, this was done with performance in mind.  So, I usually find that window functions are faster than equivalent constructs.

The only exception that I regularly find (across databases) ironically applies in your case.  And, it is not using the `join` and `group by`.  Instead it is:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.datetime = (select max(tt1.datetime)
                     from table1 tt1
                     where tt1.app_id = t1.app_id
                    );
```

Along with an index on `table1(app_id, datetime)`.

The basic reason for the performance improvement is that this scans `table1` once and does an index lookup at each row.

The `join`/`group by` is scanning the table multiple times and the aggregation is expensive.  The `row_number()` version scans the table (or index), calculates the value, and then brings the value back to every row -- similar to two scans of the data.